# Assign single value in a series to a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do I assign the value match_time to all the 3 rows that has null values in travel_min column.travel_min is a float.

I get the following error:

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

```
null_df = data[data['travel_min'].isnull()]
match_time = data.loc[data['train_station_id']==20026]['travel_min']
for row in null_df:
    row['travel_min'] = match_time
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to extract your value and then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
match_time = data.loc[data['train_station_id']==20026, 'travel_min'].iat[0]
df['travel_min'] = df['travel_min'].fillna(match_time)
```

There's no need to slice your dataframe or to use a Python-level `for` loop.

Comment: Sure, for the first line: `data['train_station_id']==20026` constructs a Boolean series for indexing, `travel_min` says which column to look in, `iat[0]` gets the first `True` match. For the second line `fillna` just fills null values with `match_time`.

Comment: So fillna fills the value passed in all the null values in my nulldf , right ?

Comment: The syntax `df['travel_min'] = df['travel_min'].fillna(match_time)` is used to fill all null values **only in `travel_min` series** with `match_time`. My solution doesn't have any `null_df`. In fact, it removes the need for `null_df`, you don't need it.

Comment: Got it ! You are my saviour. Thanks a lot !